# Feature Engineering in Python

Tags: python, data-science, one-hot-encoding, feature-engineering, label-encoding

How do I know when to apply LabelEncoder() or OneHotEncoder()?

I have used LabelEncoder to encode categorical variable for RandomForestRegressor model and it gives a extremely high mean squared error. I have tried hyperparameter tuning with GridSearchCV and it still gives the same value

Comment: This might be better suitable for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you should avoid using LabelEncoder for this:

> This transformer should be used to encode target values, i.e. y, and not the input X.

([Source.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html))

Therefore, I'd suggest using OneHotEncoder instead.

Answer (score -1):

Knowing when to apply `LabelEncoder` or `OneHotEncoder` depends on the nature of the categorical variable and the specific requirements of your machine learning model.

Here are some general guidelines:

1. `LabelEncoder`: Use `LabelEncoder` when you have an ordinal categorical variable, meaning the categories have a natural ordering or hierarchy. `LabelEncoder` assigns a unique integer label to each category, preserving the ordinal relationship. It is commonly used for encoding target variables or when working with algorithms that can directly handle ordinal labels. It's used mainly for preserving the ordinality of the target classes, and not to be used for featurr encoding. For feature encoding, you can use `OrdinalEncoder` instead.

[Check this answer for more insight](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/39317/150563)

2. `OneHotEncoder`: Use `OneHotEncoder` when you have nominal categorical variables, meaning the categories have no inherent order or hierarchy. `OneHotEncoder` creates a binary vector for each category, where a value of 1 indicates the presence of that category and 0 indicates the absence. It is suitable for algorithms that cannot directly handle categorical variables or when you want to avoid imposing any ordinal relationship among the categories.

Now, coming to the issue of high mean squared error (MSE) in your `RandomForestRegressor` model after using `LabelEncoder` on a categorical variable, it suggests that the encoded labels may not be appropriate for your model. `LabelEncoder` assigns arbitrary integer labels to categories without considering their inherent relationship. As a result, the model may perceive a false sense of ordinality or magnitude in the encoded labels, leading to suboptimal results.

In this case, you should consider using `OneHotEncoder` instead of `LabelEncoder` for your categorical variable. `OneHotEncoder` will create binary dummy variables for each category, providing a more suitable representation for your RandomForestRegressor model.

Keep in mind that using `OneHotEncoder` will expand the dimensionality of your feature matrix, so make sure to handle any potential issues such as multicollinearity or excessive memory usage that may arise from the increased number of features.

Comment: This looks like ChatGPT

Comment: Didn't get you?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).